# VMware import issue with Win7 Evaluation copy

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware

When I try to import the Win7 Evaluation copy (the ovf file) that I downloaded from Microsoft's site, first I get the following warning:

*The import failed because D:\WinVM\WinDev1903Eval.ovf did not pass OVF specification conformance or virtual hardware compliance checks.
Click Retry to relax OVF specification and virtual hardware compliance checks and try the import again, or click Cancel to cancel the import. If you retry the import, you might not be able to use the virtual machine in VMware Player.*

Then when I click retry, i get the following error:

*Failed to open virtual machine: Line 64: OVF hardware element 'ethernet0' with instance ID '5': No support for the virtual hardware device type '10'.
The guest operating system 'windows9_64Guest' is not supported.*

I checked the ovf file with an editor, everything is ordered alphabetically and everything in the *item* seems correct as well.

```
<Item>
        <rasd:AddressOnParent>1</rasd:AddressOnParent>
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>true</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Connection>nat</rasd:Connection>
        <rasd:Description>E1000 ethernet adapter on &quot;nat&quot;</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>ethernet0</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>5</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>E1000</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="slotInfo.pciSlotNumber" vmw:value="33"/>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="wakeOnLanEnabled" vmw:value="true"/>
      </Item>
```

What could be the issue? I am using Windows 10. VMware Player version is 6.0.7 build-2844087.

I tried to edit the ovf file but then VMware fails the integrity check.

The file location to be imported is on an external HDD.

Comment: Have you considered using a more recent version of VMware Player?  VMware Player 6.0 is from 2013.